# Error when add facebook sdk to Android project

Tags: android

I want to creat an app login and upload photo to facebook..
I downloaded facebook android sdk at : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk
I also done as that tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/
But in step 1: when i create a facebook sdk project,it display error at Facebook class in part:

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        messageSender = new Messenger(service);
        refreshToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg) {
        serviceListener.onError(new Error("Service disconnected"));
        // We returned an error so there's no point in
        // keeping the binding open.
        applicationsContext.unbindService(TokenRefreshServiceConnection.this);
    }
```

Image error:
http://nn7.upanh.com/b1.s28.d1/249400dcc8b86b740a9fab6679a809e3_45509157.project2.png

I don't resolve this problem so I can't do next step.:(

Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do two things:

1. link the facebook sdk to your project.
2. link the `com_facebook_android` library to your project.

You might also need to clean your project, and perhaps use the "fix project properties automatically" tool. Perhaps even restart eclipse if you still have errors.

Comment: As above,I writen : I can't add facebook sdk.I clean project but it also have error.

Comment: it looks like you're not implementing the superclass. or try removing the override annotation.

Comment: what superclass here? I removed override annotation but it aslo error

Comment: apparently it implements ServiceConnection.